# PSR[15] - LC-3 - Interrupts

Tags: assembly, interrupt, lc3

From what I understand, TRAP sets privilege bit in PSR. My question is, is it possible to manually change PSR privilege?

For example, I create and call my own-made trap, suppose trap x30 to get a char, which puts me in a privileged mode, inside that trap I save PC and PSR in a memory location, and then replace current PC and PSR in supervisor stack with a saved PC and PSR of another program, a chunk of code, which is outside of operating system. Now, can't use RTI instruction to go back to my trap because I'm not in privileged mode, so I want to change [15] bit of PSR, is it possible? Thank you!

Comment: You might use another trap to return to the privileged code to do what you want to return to the originally interrupted process.  The trap could be a simple "yield time to other" or more complicated.  In some sense this is typical of operating systems: they handle an interrupt of one process, but resume another, only later on to resume the first interrupted process.

Comment: Got it, thank makes so much sense. But in general, is it possible to change the privilege or priority status of PSR manually without going into OS? Thanks again!

Comment: IMHO, user code should not have the permission to raise its own privilege.  The idea being that the operating system is trusted and user code not so much.  So, asking the operating system is the way to raise privilege.  More specifically, for LC-3, there is no mov to PSR instruction, and if there was it would be privileged like RTI (or else, it would only update the condition codes and not affect the privilege bit).